About commutator of operators regarding operator splitting
I'm currently reading chapter 4 in "Numerical Solution of Time-Dependent Advection-Diffusion-Reaction Equations" (Hundsdorfer, Verwer) and i'm stuck at understanding the commutator operator. At the moment, they work with the advection diffusion equation
$$u_t = -\Delta \cdot (\underline{a}u) + \Delta \cdot (D \nabla u)$$
Since we are interested in splitting, consider $\mathbf{f}_A (u) = -\Delta \cdot (\underline{a}u), \mathbf{f}_D = \Delta \cdot (D\nabla u)$. Lie's Bassic Splitting is accurate if the commutator of both advection and diffusion part:
$$[\mathbf{f}_A, \mathbf{f}_D](u) = \mathbf{f}_A' (u) \mathbf{f}_D (u) - \mathbf{f}_D ' (u) \mathbf{f}_A(u)$$
vanishes identically. Now comes the part that I don't understand: It's stated that $\mathbf{f}_A ' (u) v = - \Delta \cdot (\underline{a}v) = \mathbf{f}_A (v)$. How is this true? As far as I know, the derivatives $\mathbf{f}_A ' (u)$ are understood componentwise, but I still don't know how to interpret the action of such derivative over $v$. I have the same struggle with the diffusion operator, where $\mathbf{f}_D '(u)v = \mathbf{f}_D (v)$ again. Any help will be appreciated.

I think that the derivative is interpreted as a Frechet derivative.
